# TinyMCE in SPFx web part, on SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, spfx, react, rich-text

I am using SharePoint 2019 on prem, and developing a web part where I am using tinymce editor. In our Productions environment there is no internet access, so I need to add the tinymce as self-hosted. The tinymce editor has a property called `tinymceScriptSrc` where I can specify the the tinymce.min.js file.

I tried to put the min.js file in a folder in my SPFx project, and referenced to it like this, but this approach didn't work:

```
tinymceScriptSrc="./path/tinymce.min.js"
```

I downloaded all the files required for tinymce, and uploaded them in an Asset library in SharePoint, and referenced it to the `tinymceScriptSrc` with an absoloute URL, and then it worked.

```
   <Editor
        value={category.content}                         
        tinymceScriptSrc="<url>/Style%20Library/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"
    ......
</Editor>
```

.. but this approach will require me to upload the tinymce-files in an asset library using features and modules, and I want to avoid that.

Any suggestions for how I can implement self-hosted tinymce in a SPFx webpart on a SharePoint 2019 on prem environment where we don't have internet access.

Thanks.